# Can TOR Browser be used with proxychains?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

i configured proxychains to use TOR and enabled No DNS Leak,
i installed TOR and it's working fine (masking my IP and DNS).
I also downloaded TOR Browser to use instead of firefox.
Can someone help me , what is the best and safest way to use Tor Browser anonymously? 
can be used along with proxychains like? 
$ proxychains tor address
 or how can i do that?
(Even i'll be pleased if there is a safest way to use Tor Browser)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Tor FAQ](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#Proxychains):

> Proxychains is a program that sends your traffic through a series of
>   open web proxies that you supply before sending it on to your final
>   destination. Unlike Tor, proxychains does not encrypt the connections
>   between each proxy server. An open proxy that wanted to monitor your
>   connection could see all the other proxy servers you wanted to use
>   between itself and your final destination, as well as the IP address
>   that proxy hop received traffic from.
>
> Because the Tor protocol requires encrypted relay-to-relay
>   connections, not even a misbehaving relay can see the entire path of
>   any Tor user.
>
> While Tor relays are run by volunteers and checked periodically for
>   suspicious behavior, many open proxies that can be found with a search
>   engine are compromised machines, misconfigured private proxies not
>   intended for public use, or honeypots set up to exploit users.